# What should I do about outdated BootCache playlists?

Tags: startup, macos

In `/private/var/db/BootCaches` there are old 'bootcache playlists' (not clear what these exactly are as they also have some sort of user component apparently) for Coriolis Systems (which in the past had iDefrag and iPartition, but which now has been shut down because of APFS). I've removed as much as I could find from Coriolis Systems software, but this remains and rebuilding the boot cache and rebooting hasn't changed that.

How do I really clean this up? Here is the output of `ls`

```
bash-3.2# ls /private/var/db/BootCaches
72499DE8-BFC3-4A73-AC46-2EFBCAA4F257    PreheatedUser
FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA000000F8    Root.logical_playlist
FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA000001F5    RootExtra.logical_playlist
Login.logical_playlist
bash-3.2# ls /private/var/db/BootCaches/*
/private/var/db/BootCaches/Login.logical_playlist
/private/var/db/BootCaches/Root.logical_playlist
/private/var/db/BootCaches/RootExtra.logical_playlist

/private/var/db/BootCaches/72499DE8-BFC3-4A73-AC46-2EFBCAA4F257:
Login.playlist
app.com.agilebits.onepassword-osx.playlist
app.com.apple.ActivityMonitor.playlist
app.com.apple.Console.playlist
app.com.apple.Safari.playlist
app.com.apple.Terminal.playlist
app.com.apple.TextEdit.playlist
app.com.apple.systempreferences.playlist
app.com.backup42.desktop.playlist
app.com.coriolis-systems.iDefrag.playlist
app.com.coriolis-systems.iPartition.playlist

/private/var/db/BootCaches/FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA000000F8:
Login.playlist

/private/var/db/BootCaches/FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA000001F5:

/private/var/db/BootCaches/PreheatedUser:
Login.playlist
app.com.agilebits.onepassword-osx.playlist
app.com.apple.ActivityMonitor.playlist
app.com.apple.Console.playlist
app.com.apple.Safari.playlist
app.com.apple.Terminal.playlist
app.com.apple.TextEdit.playlist
app.com.apple.systempreferences.playlist
app.com.backup42.desktop.playlist
app.com.coriolis-systems.iDefrag.playlist
app.com.coriolis-systems.iPartition.playlist
```

Comment: Unsure; do you mean: you deleted the coriolis-related files in BootCaches by hand and after reboot (and only after reboot, not just after a while) they re-appeared?

Comment: I deleted eveything Coriolis that I could find, _except_ these two in BootCaches. But from the answer I gather that I can safely delete these.

Answer (score 1):

These files are used for boot-time optimisation. The cache is also measured for hit rate, and stores the request pattern into a "history list" for being adaptive in future. If the hit rate is too low, the caching is disabled.

To look under the hood and examine the hit/miss rate

```
 sudo bootcachecontrol statistics Print
```

The actual impact of files like `app.com.coriolis-systems.iDefrag.playlist` should be really minimal.

However, if the application is otherwise completely gone, it is safe to delete all instances of these coriolis-related cache files *in* `/private/var/db/BootCaches/`

If these files get recreated it means that there are remnants of the application left, *and* active.

(Observe this effect by deleting `/private/var/db/BootCaches/PreheatedUser/app.com.apple.Safari.playlist` It will be created instantly once you relaunch Safari)